# Create hotspot in raspbian

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, raspbian, wifi-hotspot, hostapd

I have a RPI 2 with raspbian OS. I have a WI-FI USB adapter too that it is connected to the pi. I want to use wlan0 as a hotspot but any try get failed. I tried [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md) guide and some open source project like [RaspAP](https://github.com/billz/raspap-webgui) too and all of them outputs was this:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

I'm using [this](http://www.pix-link.com/page50?product_id=26) adapter and it worked in windows 10 correctly. It support SoftAP (I don't know what is it exactly and what is the difference with AP!). However this adapter support only managed and monitor modes.
If it works in windows why it dose not work in raspbian?
Where is the problem?

Additional intel: it works in client mode fine.

**UPDATE**

chipset: 802.11n

Sorry I didn't know what lines of outputs are need so I put all the outputs in the below file.

dmesg, lsmod and lsusb
[outputs](https://textuploader.com/1ebmc)

Comment: Which chipset is the dongle based on? Which driver are you using? Please post the relevant lines from `dmesg`, `lsmod` and perhaps `lsusb`.

Comment: According to [a question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation), the `rt2800` module is needed.  Make sure you have that loaded.

Comment: According to [elinux.org](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters), that may need manual driver compilation/installation.  You can search in that page for `148f:7601`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RPi USB Wi-Fi Adapters listings on elinux.org](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters), that device may need manual compilation and installation of the rt2800 driver.  Also, that's reported to not work with the default version of `hostapd`.

> RT5370 USB-ID 148f:7601 Advertised on eBay as RT5370 chipset but has Mediatek 7601T chip instead. [9] DOES NOT WORK out of the box; requires compiling a driver downloadable from mediatek.com or from github.com. MT7601 doesn't work with default hostapd.

**References**

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=95540
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=49864&
  hilit=mt7601
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation
- https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters